# Converting mbox to HTML

Tags: html, mbox

Is there a simple way to convert mbox files to HTML pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Hypermail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hypermail/) or [MHonArc](http://www.mhonarc.org/). They are used to create HTML mailing list archives from mbox files. Maybe one of them fits your needs.

Comment: also Pipermail (though I can't seem to find a working version anywhere).